# Migrate TFS Changesets

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, tfs-migration, tfs-to-tfs-migration-tool

I assumed this would be easy, but I'm not finding anything on it...

I have a project in TFS 2010, which needs to be moved to a new TFS 2015 server. Apparently the project cannot simply be moved normally because it's using a different project template which is not compatible and causes errors when trying to migrate (so I'm told - I don't have any more details on this).

I'm looking for a way to bring over the changesets, keeping history, to the new server. I assumed there was some kind of "dump" where you could export the TFS changesets, then import them into the new server into an empty project - but I'm not finding that option.

[TFS Integration](http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/) is deprecated and apparently doesn't work for TFS2015, with no alternative listed.

I'm open to other creative options like temporarily exporting to a different version control system - for example, I've looked at [SVNBridge](http://svnbridge.codeplex.com), but I can't even get that working, let alone figure out if it would help here.

Is there a way to migrate all changesets for a given project and keep history, without migrating the entire project?

Comment: You have to migrate just a single project and can't migrate the entire team project collection? Git-TFS would probably serve your purpose here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no default way to migrate changesets in TFS, you would need 3rd party tool, like [OpsHub](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1455028.OpsHubVisualStudioOnlineMigrationUtility) (some features are not free), to migrate the most commonly requested data. Check: http://www.opshub.com/products/opshub-visual-studio-migration-utility/

Or you may consider doing a upgrade from TFS 2010 to TFS 2015, which is a full data transfer. To understand factors that affect your upgrade's compexity, [check the requirements](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/requirements) and [review the upgrade process](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/upgrade/get-started).

Learn if a dry run makes sense for you, and weigh the benefits and the costs to perform a [pre-production upgrade](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/upgrade/pre-production).

When you're ready to upgrade, minimize downtime with the [TfsPreUpgrade tool](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/upgrade/pre-upgrade) - especially for very large TFS collection databases (> 1 TB). Follow these steps for [how to upgrade TFS](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/upgrade/walkthrough).

Comment: Ouch, a $10K price tag on that utility - looks like the free edition doesn't support regular in-house TFS-to-TFS migration. And I'm not in a position to change the upgrade process - that was already done by another team last year - so I think I'll keep looking. Thanks for the info - looks like it could definitely be helpful if things were a little different.